# .net application setup default path as user folder

Tags: .net, setup-deployment

My .net desktop application ready for setup file creation, i want to install this application in user folder to avoid admin permissions. i want to set the path like

```
C:\Users\[logonuser]\[ProductName]
```

for this i'm checking the setup-> file system -> Application folder-> properties, default path there is like

```
[ProgramFilesFolder][Manufacturer]\[ProductName]
```

this path installs my application in program files, so my question is, how to write new path dynamically which represents path

```
C:\Users\userA\application name\
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just use :

`Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile)` this will return the user path

Comment: inside c# code this method works but i want to know what should i write inside default location as shown in image?

Comment: then try SHORTCUTDIR check this link https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/folder-paths.html